# Converting datetime to be mysql format using python

Tags: python, mysql, date, datetime, csv

I am trying to convert a date format in Excel to be formatted such that it can be read into a MySQL database. I am using python to process the date column, export it back into a csv file and then dump it into a MySQL table.

Here is how the date column look like :

```
Date
6/10/13
6/17/13
6/24/13
```

I want it to be in the format : 2013-06-10 or ("%Y-%m-%d")

Here is my code:

```
import datetime
import csv

def read(filename):
  new_date=[]

  cr = csv.reader(open(filename,"rU").readlines()[1:], dialect='excel')
  for row in cr:
    # print row[0]
    cols=datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0] , "%m/%d/%y" )
    newcols=cols.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    # print newcols
    new_date.append(newcols)
  print new_date[0]
  with open('new_file.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for date in new_date:
        writer.writerow([date])
```

The code runs, but when i open the new_file.csv, the date column automatically reverts back to the old format in excel.

How can i change this?

Thanks,

Comment: I would think this is to be expected. Your output to `new_file.csv` is correct, but Excel recognizes that your are supplying dates, and is displaying it according to its default date formatting. If what you want to import into MySQL is the CSV file, I'd say you're on the right track and don't need to worry about how Excel displays things.

Comment: Ok, and just wondering, instead of writing to a new file, can i write it back to the same file and just replace the date format in the date column?

Comment: That question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020858/inline-csv-file-editing-with-python

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening the .csv in a simple text editor (like notepad, for example) to see if the date is being printed to that file correctly?  My guess is that Excel, which has the ability to recognize dates, is just reformatting it to it's default date format when you open the file, and that if you open your .csv file in a simple text editor to check, you'll see that your code has correctly reformatted the dates in the csv.

(By default, Excel formats dates like you specify in Control Panel, and you can change your default date formatting in Control Panel to change Excel's default formatting.)

You can change the way that Excel formats dates [as described here in the documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/format-a-date-the-way-you-want-HA102809474.aspx).

> 1. Select the cells you want to format.
> 2. Press CTRL+1.
> 3. In the Format Cells box, click the Number tab.
> 4. In the Category list, click Date.

You can create a custom date format from this menu if the format you see is not there.  Details [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/format-a-date-the-way-you-want-HA102809474.aspx#_Toc320186183).

Comment: Even in the format box, there are some options to change the date format but there are no option to make it the format that MySQL accepts.

Comment: See the link in the last word of my answer for how to create a custom date format.  However, I don't think you need to care how Excel displays things as long as things are correct in your .csv file.  I would open it in a text editor, not Excel, to check the date format.