# How to insert deplicated rows based on values of specific cells in one column

Tags: python, excel, insert, copy

As title, I have one Excel file containing data like photo below,
[image]

Now I want to edit the file based on data in column C **(Numbers of coming late)**:

I want to copy every row in the file based on their values in column C, and insert them just below the original record, as shown in the photo below,

[image]

That is, the numbers of copying depend on values in column C:

Tom came late 2 times, so I want a total of 2 rows of his record,

Jack just came late one time, his record remains one time (row),

Jane came late 3 times, I want there would be total 3 rows of her record.

How could I achieve this? Could I do this just use Excel itself or should I use other computer languages, like Python? Please give me some advice, thanks.

Comment: `How could I achieve this?` Fairly straightforward if you think about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Python, this will read from your CSV, write to a temporary one, then overwrite the original file at the end. The code to do that is borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/a/16020923/2766903
You just have to write each row 1 time per Numbers of coming in late.

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import shutil
import csv

filename = 'path-to-excel-file.csv'
tempfile = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)

with open(filename, 'rb') as csvFile, tempfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    writer = csv.writer(tempfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

    for row in reader:
        late_count = int(row['Numbers of coming late'])
        for i in range(0, late_count):
            writer.writerow(row)

shutil.move(tempfile.name, filename)
```