# Writing into certain csv columns using python

Tags: python, csv, geocoding

I have a list of addresses and using GeoPy I'm getting the longitude and latitude. Everything works great but now I want to insert the longitude and latitude into the same csv file, so latitude in the 8th column and longitude in the 9th column.

```
AREA, ADDRESS1, ADDRESS2, ADDRESS3, ADDRESS4, ADDRESS7, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE
NORRKÖPING, Fridtunga, 602 28, Norrköping,SE        
NORRKÖPING, Björnatan gata 131, 603 77, Norrköping,SE
```

Above is the csv file I am extracting info out of. I am taking address 2 and 4 and getting longitude and latitude with them

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import csv

geolocator = Nominatim()

with open('test.csv', 'r') as in_file:
reader = csv.reader(in_file)
for row in reader:
    adress1 = row[3]
    adress2 = row[5]
    locaiton = geolocator.geocode(adress1 + " " + adress2)
    if locaiton is not None and locaiton.longitude is not None and locaiton.latitude is not None:
        print(adress1 + " " + adress2 + " ", locaiton.latitude, locaiton.longitude)
        out_file = open('test.csv', 'w')
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        row[6] = locaiton.latitude
        row[7] = locaiton.longitude
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Last part is the part I can't figure out. How can I make it so it keeps going on in the rows? right now it puts the longitude and latitude in the same row, deleting the previous ones.

Right now the the csv file looks like:

```
NORRKÖPING, Björnatan gata 131, 603 77, Norrköping,SE,58.5888632,16.186094499284,
```

but I'd like it to look like:

```
 NORRKÖPING, Fridtunga, 602 28, Norrköping,SE, 58.5649201, 16.217851        
 NORRKÖPING, Björnatan gata 131, 603 77, Norrköping,SE,58.5888632,16.186094499284,
```

Comment: Your cvs file is correct ? I could write a script with Numpy but I saw 8 columns in first line and then 5 elements

Comment: Yeah, its correct I couldn't copy the first column. I could try to install numpy or Pandas but I already have a working first half of the program.

Comment: You're overwriting the `test.csv` file on each iteration. This is because the open mode is `w`. You have to open output file and create writer before you begin iterate. Right after the `rows` initialized.

Comment: @frist, I moved it infront, but now it just leaves the file empty.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use the Pandas package - all CSV operations will become trivial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be changing files in place when you are adding stuff. [Check this question for that dicussion.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020858/inline-csv-file-editing-with-python) However, you can create a new file with the desired output.

Assuming that your code works, try doing this I rearranged few lines.

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import csv

geolocator = Nominatim()

with open('test.csv','r') as in_file:
    reader = csv.reader(in_file)
    out_file = open('out.csv', 'w')
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    for row in reader:
        adress1 = row[3]
        adress2 = row[5]
        locaiton = geolocator.geocode(adress1 + " " + adress2)
        if locaiton is not None and locaiton.longitude is not None and locaiton.latitude is not None:
            print(adress1 + " " + adress2 + " ", locaiton.latitude, locaiton.longitude)
            row.append(locaiton.latitude) 
            row.append(locaiton.longitude)
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Right now the my code atleast prints out the cordinates, and adds the them into the first row in the correct column. it keeps removing the previous. Do you maybe know how to keep going downward with it?

Comment: Can you edit the question and show a sample of what output file you are getting? I don't completely understand what you mean by removing the previous. And try the code that I posted, and see what output this one gives.

Comment: Yeah i edited the output. I ment that it overwrote the previous addres instead of moving one row downward. Saddly your code just returns blank deleting the info in csv file.

Comment: I updated the answer, I changed the file names - it is important. You cannot modify the file in-place.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll remeber to create a new file instead of editind last one. Thank you again!