# Ascending read from csv and update csv using python

Tags: python, csv

I want to know whether it is possible to read the `.csv` file with specific `row`, after reading the row. I want to delete that specific row and update the `.csv` file with next row gets ascended. Assuming the `.csv` file has headers. If it is possible than how?
Ex. below is my `sample.csv`

```
Time A B
12:25 5.6 4.5
12:30 1.2 -3.4
12:35 4.7 -4.0
```

Below is the code I have tried:

```
import csv
with open('sample.csv', 'rb') as inp, open('sample.csv', "a") as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out)
    for row in csv.reader(inp):
        writer.writerow(row)
```

But it gets, appended at the end of file. I have also tried to write it on the temporary file for intermediate stage. But, it still not serve my purpose cause I have to work on the same file. Here is the output `sample.csv`, which I want after one iteration of read:

```
Time A B
12:30 1.2 -3.4
12:35 4.7 -4.0
```

Comment: Yes it's possible, can you show your efforts

Comment: @EdChum I am new at `python`. I have gone through [basic links] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020858/inline-csv-file-editing-with-python). Implement that code could not serve my purpose.

Comment: As @EdChum said, please try something and post it here, we will guide you through.

Comment: @e-nouri I have edited my question.

Comment: you want to work on the same file, did you understood the code you posted ?

Comment: Work on a temp file AND overwrite the original after saving the changes.

Comment: @xbello Can you provide me the snippet? How it can be done?

Comment: It's on the accepted answer of the question you linked before. The last line, with the `shutil` code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `StringIO` to keep the contents in memory and then write them to the desired file at the end.

```
from io import StringIO
import csv

filename = 'sample.csv'
out_data = StringIO()

# Read CSV data to memory
with open(filename, 'r', newline='') as in_file:
    writer = csv.writer(out_data)
    for row in csv.reader(in_file):
        writer.writerow(row)

# Write intermediate data to file
with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as out_file:
    out_file.write(out_data.getvalue())

out_data.close()
```