# Editing an open csv file

Tags: python, csv, generator

How could I edit the contents of an open csv file before I run it through the csv reader?

```
csvfile = open(input, mode='r', newline='', encoding='utf-8') # opening csv file 

for line in csvfile:
    line = line.replace(",", ";") #replacing comma with semicolon
    print(line) # test if replace was successful (working) 

csvfile.seek(0) # return to the beginning of the file 

csv_read = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=";", quotechar='"') # use reader
```

This isn't working as I had hoped and csv.reader still reads the old unedited file.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Why not just use the original delimiter?! Note that `line =` just reassigns that name in the loop, it **does not** alter the underlying file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inline CSV File Editing with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020858/inline-csv-file-editing-with-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a generator to allow editing the `csv` file on the fly.  This does not actually edit the file, it simply modifies what the `csv` reader sees.

**Code:**

```
def edit_csv_on_fly(csv_file):
    for line in csv_file.readlines():
        # replacing comma with semicolon
        yield line.replace(",", ";")
```

**Test Code:**

```
import csv
with open('myfile.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
    csv_read = csv.reader(
        edit_csv_on_fly(csvfile), delimiter=";", quotechar='"')
    for row in csv_read:
        print(row)
```

**Test Data:**

```
"COLUMN A","COLUMN B","COLUMN C","COLUMN D","COLUMN E"
"COLUMN A","COLUMN B","COLUMN C","COLUMN D","COLUMN E"
"COLUMN A","COLUMN B","COLUMN C","COLUMN D";"COLUMN E"
```

**Results:**

```
['COLUMN A', 'COLUMN B', 'COLUMN C', 'COLUMN D', 'COLUMN E']
['COLUMN A', 'COLUMN B', 'COLUMN C', 'COLUMN D', 'COLUMN E']
['COLUMN A', 'COLUMN B', 'COLUMN C', 'COLUMN D', 'COLUMN E']
```