# Open a csv file in 'rb' mode and iterate over it

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I've seen an older answer for the post, [Inline CSV File Editing with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020858/inline-csv-file-editing-with-python#16020923), about how to modify a csv file and save it. It uses the tempfile module. I have used the same code in Python 3.6 but I get an error because I read the file in binary mode and I cannot iterate over it.

The code below creates a simple CSV file

```
import csv

with open('proglanguages.csv', mode='w', newline='') as csv_file:
    fieldnames = ['lang', 'value']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writerow({'lang': 'Java', 'value': '90'})
    writer.writerow({'lang': 'c', 'value': '80'})
    writer.writerow({'lang': 'Perl', 'value': '78'})
    writer.writerow({'lang': 'C++', 'value': '92'})
    writer.writerow({'lang': 'Python', 'value': '0'})
    writer.writerow({'lang': 'Fortran', 'value': '70'})
```

The code below modifies the previous generated CSV file,

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import shutil
import csv

filename = 'proglanguages.csv'
tempfile = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)


with open(filename, mode='rb') as csvFile, tempfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    writer = csv.writer(tempfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

    for row in reader:
        if row[0] == 'Python':
            row[1] = '100'
            writer.writerow(row)
        else:
            writer.writerow(row)

shutil.move(tempfile.name, filename)
```

In which way, could I use the for-loop for iteration, modify the item and write in the tempfile

Comment: The mode should be `'r'` for `csv.reader` and `'w'` for `csv.writer`.

Comment: The requirement to read a text file as binary is curious, can you explain why this is necessary? This smacks of an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: @tripleee Opening as binary is a requirement for csv reader/writer on Python 2.  The module manages newlines directly.  Python 3's csv requires newline='' instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not lucky here. Answers from Martijn Pieters are always high quality ones. This one was but was targetted at Python 2 while you use Python 3. And the csv semantics have changed... You should no longer use binary mode in Python 3 and do what you did for the initial csv file:

```
...
tempfile = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, newline='', mode='w')

with open(filename, mode='r', newline='') as csvFile, tempfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    writer = csv.writer(tempfile)
    ...
```

Comment: I think you may need to set `wt` for the temp file explicitly. If I'm not mistaken, they open in binary mode by default.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: The default is indeed `'w+b'` but it is enough to set the mode to `'w'` (just tested under Windows...).

Comment: @SergeBallesta Yes it works. I have suspected the version of the Python and I have tried different modes in `open()` but I had no idea for the `NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, newline='', mode='w')`