# How to execute a function and save in a new csv file?

Tags: python-3.x

This program converts coordinates. What I am trying to do is to

1. use a csv file as input
2. use the function to convert the coordinates
3. save the output as a new csv file.

My file (worksheet.csv)  has three columns, latitude, longitude and height.

How would I approach this?

```
import math
import csv


# semi-major axis of earth
a = 6378137.0

# 1/f is reciprocal of flatteing 
f= 0.00335281068

# converts the input from degree to radians
latitude = math.radians(float(input('Enter Latitude:')))
longitude = math.radians(float(input('Enter Longitude:')))
height  = float(input('Enter Height:'))

def earthConverter(latitude, longitude, height):
    e = math.sqrt((2 * f) - (f**2))
    N = a / math.sqrt(1-e**2 * math.sin(latitude)**2)

    x = (N + height) * math.cos(latitude) * math.cos(longitude)
    y = (N + height) * math.cos(latitude) * math.sin(longitude)
    z = (N * (1 - e**2 ) + height) * math.sin(latitude)


    return x, y, z



############################################

with open('worksheet.csv', 'r') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    for row in reader:
        writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
        writer.writerow(row[0], row[1], row[2], earthConverter(math.radians(float(row[0])),
            earthConverter(math.radians(float(row[1])), earthConverter(float(row[2])) )


csvFile.close()
```

Comment: With this much information it is difficult to understand the problem, Please provide your input file and expected output file format. Also what errors you are getting in this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've very close, but there are several things that need to be changed. Here's what I think is a full solution, but below I'll work through each part of the code

```
import math
import csv

def earthConverter(latitude, longitude, height):
    f = 0.00335281068
    a = 6378137.0
    e = math.sqrt((2 * f) - (f**2))
    N = a / math.sqrt(1-e**2 * math.sin(latitude)**2)
    x = (N + height) * math.cos(latitude) * math.cos(longitude)
    y = (N + height) * math.cos(latitude) * math.sin(longitude)
    z = (N * (1 - e**2 ) + height) * math.sin(latitude)
    return x, y, z

with open('worksheet.csv', 'r') as Infile, open('worksheet_out.csv', 'w') as Outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(Infile)
    # next(reader, None)
    writer = csv.writer(Outfile)
    for row in reader:
        lat = math.radians(float(row[0]))
        lon = math.radians(float(row[1]))
        ht = math.radians(float(row[2]))
        x, y, z = earthConverter(lat, lon, ht)
        row_out = [row[0], row[1], row[2], x, y, z]
        writer.writerow(row_out)
```

First, you can move the definitions of `f` and `a` into the `earthConverter` function itself to avoid any possible problems with [variable scoping](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces). This isn't strictly necessary.

Second, you can get rid of the `latitude = math.radians(float(input('Enter Latitude:')))` lines. Those ask for user input, which is not what you want here.

Third, you cannot write back to the same csv. You've opened it in read mode (`'r'`), but even if you changed that, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16020923/4325492) gives some details about why that won't work/is a bad idea. You can also get rid of the separate call to close the csv at the end of your code -- the `with open()` construction takes care of that for you.

Fourth, your `earthConverter` function returns a tuple, so you need to unpack those values somehow before trying to write them out again.

Everything in the `for row in reader:` block could be condensed into fewer rows. I broke it up this way because it makes it a little easier to read.

Also, you didn't mention whether your input csv had a header. If it does, then uncomment the line `next(reader, None)`, which will skip the header. If you need to write a header out again, then you could change the `for row in reader:` block to this:

```
for i, row in enumerate(reader):
    if i == 1:
        header_out = ['lat', 'lon', 'ht', 'x', 'y', 'z'] # or whatever
        writer.writerow(header_out)
    lat = math.radians(float(row[0]))
    lon = math.radians(float(row[1]))
    ht = math.radians(float(row[2]))
    x, y, z = earthConverter(lat, lon, ht)
    row_out = [row[0], row[1], row[2], x, y, z]
    writer.writerow(row_out)
```

Comment: All the converted points are saved in the worksheet_out now. This is a much better way of using the function,  instead of inputting everything directly in the writer.writerow !

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is create a Dataframe to read the csv file and create a for loop to iterate through each row so and insert it into a new Dataframe. Then we let the panda library Export it into a new csv file.

```
import pandas as pd
import math


# semi-major axis of earth
a = 6378137.0

# 1/f is reciprocal of flatteing
f = 0.00335281068


def earthConverter(latitude, longitude, height):
    e = math.sqrt((2 * f) - (f**2))
    N = a / math.sqrt(1-e**2 * math.sin(latitude)**2)

    x = (N + height) * math.cos(latitude) * math.cos(longitude)
    y = (N + height) * math.cos(latitude) * math.sin(longitude)
    z = (N * (1 - e**2 ) + height) * math.sin(latitude)

    return x, y, z


def new_csv(input_file, output_file):
    df = pd.read_csv(input_file)
    points_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Height'])
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        x1, y1, z1 = earthConverter(row['Latitude'], row['Longitude'], row['Height'])
        temp_df = pd.DataFrame({'Latitude': x1,
                                'Longitude': y1,
                                'Height': z1}, index=[0])
        points_df = points_df.append(temp_df, ignore_index=True)

    points_df.to_csv(output_file)


new_csv('worksheet.csv', 'new_worksheet.csv')
```