# How can I set a value from a function to a CSV?

Tags: python, csv

I am a new coder trying to build a twitter bot that automatically tweets based on some data I have created. Right now, I want to set a tweet that I grabbed as "tweeted". I want to open the CSV and set the field "tweeted" with a "1".

I have read quite a bit but I am having a hard time with the examples because they don't pertain to my code. (Again, sorry I'm new.)

This is what I have so far to get to the row that I have already tweeted

```
def markastweeted():
    """Sets tweeted field to 1"""
    with open("data.csv", "r+") as csvDataFile:
        quotesdb = list(csv.DictReader(csvDataFile))
        for line in quotesdb:

            #Field names in CSV
            #----- id_serial
            #----- id_season
            #----- quote
            #----- file_path
            #----- id_group
            #----- trigger_time
            #----- tweeted

            #----- check "tweeted" field for data -- if true go to next row
            if line['tweeted'] == ("1"):
                pass

            if line['tweeted'] == (""):
```

In my other function that returns the tweet, I have:

```
if line['tweeted'] == (""):
     return line['tweet']
```

but here I would like to have something like this:

```
if line['tweeted'] == (""):
     set line['tweeted'] with "1"
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16020858/2445273

Comment: @LoMaPh I already looked into that thread and it's a little above my head. I am looking for a more helpful explanation as I am completely new.

Comment: Every time you want to make a change, read the CSV file line by line and write to another file as you read each line. For the edit part, while reading each line, check if it matches your criteria and make the edit on that specific line. This edited line gets written in the second file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to modify csv files, you need to read them in memory as you did in `csv.DictReader(csvDataFile)` store information in a variable, modify the variable, then define another writer like `csv.DictWriter(csvDataFile, headers)` then use `writerows(rows)` to write back to the file

your code should looks like:

```
def markastweeted():
    """Sets tweeted field to 1"""
    with open("data.csv", "r", newline='') as csvDataFile:
        r = csv.DictReader(csvDataFile)
        fieldnames = r.fieldnames
        quotesdb = [row for row in r]

        for line in quotesdb:

            #Field names in CSV
            #----- id_serial
            #----- id_season
            #----- quote
            #----- file_path
            #----- id_group
            #----- trigger_time
            #----- tweeted

            #----- check "tweeted" field for data -- if true go to next row
            if not line['tweeted']:
                line['tweeted'] == 1

    # writing back to file **(OVERWRITE)**
    with open("data.csv", "w", newline='') as fout:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(fout, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(quotesdb)
```